# immersions of low dimensional projective spaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

It was proved by Hirsch in (I think) 1959 that 3-dimensional real projective space can be immersed in 4 dimensional Euclidean space. Does anyone know an explicit immersion? Ditto for immersions of 4-dimensional
real projective space in low dimensional Euclidean space.